# What is the difference between creating struct with reference and creating one without it in GoLang?

Tags: go

If I have a struct like this

```
type car struct {
    name  string
    color string
}

func (c *car) repaint(newColor string) {
    c.color = newColor
}
```

The output following code block is same:

block-1

```
    myCar := car{
        name:  "honda",
        color: "white",
    }

    yourCar := car{
        name:  "honda",
        color: "white",
    }

    fmt.Println(myCar.color, yourCar.color)

    myCar.repaint("green")

    fmt.Println(myCar.color, yourCar.color)
```

block-2

```
    myCar := &car{
        name:  "honda",
        color: "white",
    }

    yourCar := &car{
        name:  "honda",
        color: "white",
    }

    fmt.Println(myCar.color, yourCar.color)

    myCar.repaint("green")

    fmt.Println(myCar.color, yourCar.color)
```

I see alot of places devs create variable with reference to struc. Why do they do that?

Comment: Try passing `myCar` into a function and `repaint` it inside the function. Then check `myCar.color` (inside the function and in the `main` function. Do that for both cases and see what happens.

Comment: Note that in `block-1` when calling `repaint` Go takes a pointer of `myCar`. That is because it is not a pointer but `repaint` is attached on a pointer (`*car`). It needs to take a pointer to be able to call the `repaint` method.

Comment: Something else you can try: Create an interface (let's call it `Paintable`) with a `repaint(color string)` method. Then define `myCar` as `var myCar Paintable`. Try to assign `car{}` and `&car{}`. You will see only the second is possible, because `car` does not implement the interface. The `repaint` method is attached to `*car` so only `*car` (with a pointer) implements the interface.

Comment: The name is "Go" and there are no references in Go: A point is not a "reference".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is done in order to make clear that the variable in question is a pointer to said struct. In a simple example like yours, it does not make a difference, that is true. However, with a slightly more complex example, the use becomes clear:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type car struct {
    name  string
    color string
}

func (c *car) repaint(newColor string) {
    c.color = newColor
}

func (c *car) describe() {
    fmt.Printf("This car is a %s and is %s\n", c.name, c.color)
}

// changeColor has the parameter c, which is the value of a car.
// Basically, the value is copied and the original car is not modified.
func changeColor(c car, newColor string) {
    c.repaint(newColor)
}

// changeColorProperly has the parameter c, which is a pointer to
// a car. Thus, calling repaint on it the original struct is modified.
func changeColorProperly(c *car, newColor string) {
    c.repaint(newColor)
}

func main() {

    // myCar is a pointer to a car
    myCar := &car{name: "Toyota", color: "red"}
    myCar.describe()
    // Output: This car is a Toyota and is red

    // Note the dereference operator. Here, we pass the **value**
    // to which myCar points
    changeColor(*myCar, "blue")
    myCar.describe()
    // Output: This car is a Toyota and is red

    // Now, we pass the pointer.
    changeColorProperly(myCar, "blue")
    myCar.describe()
}
```

<kbd>**[Run on playground](https://go.dev/play/p/w5__yIzK9mg)**</kbd>

So, if you want a function to modify the original struct, you'd pass by reference (almost always a good idea, since as you have already noticed, it does not make much of a difference in usage) and only if you are absolutely positively sure that you want the function to receive a copy of the original struct, you'd pass by value.